# Swift and/or ObjC memory leak when having a default non-lazy property in a bridged Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks

We have a weird memory leak, but since the code is closed source I can't just post the code so I'll do my best to make sure the important bits are available.

## **Disclaimers:**

1. I can't post the complete backtrace, but if you want to see it I'll do my best to produce an obfuscated version
2. I can't post complete class definitions, but I am including the parts that have been run in this scenario, obfuscated.

**What I hope to learn**

I want to know why this happens, not get a solution. Or perhaps when I know what happens, I'll know how to better solve it if there's a better way than making them `lazy`.

## Problem

**These default values leak**

Pricing:

```swift
@objcMembers
class Pricing: Mappable {
    var price: Money = Money.zero()
    var vat: Percent = Percent.zero()

    ...
}
```

## Some related information

These two properties leak. From what I can gather, these instances of zero are immediately lost as our ObjC interface `Mappable` has a category called `Mappable+JSONMappings` which provides a default implementation of our JSON deserialisation initialised, `initWithJSON:`, in Objective C for all objects that implement `Mappable`. This means that all you have to do is claim to implement it, and then you get this initialiser which is then called by our deserialiser, magic!

However, we get two separate leaks every time we deserialise this `Pricing` object. One for the `Money` class and its internal `NSDecimalNumber` and one for `Percent`. Fixing `Money` fixes `NSDecimalNumber`. This is consistent and they leak the exact same way when I look at the memory graph.

`Mappable` was originally used only by our ObjC models, as our Swift models we had up until this point were structs that implemented `Codable` to achieve the same result, just using `JSONDecoder`. This model had to be used in the legacy parts of our system and thus needed to also use `Mappable`, but we went with Swift in order to use Swift features not available in ObjC, such as `enum Enum: String` and such, which are used internally by `Pricing` for whatever reasons.

Money.m:

```c
@interface Money()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *value;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currencyCode;

@end

@implementation Money

+ (instancetype)zero {
    return [Money initWithDecimal:[@(0) decimalValue]];
}

+ (instancetype)initWithDecimal:(NSDecimal)decimal {
    return [[self alloc] initWithDecimal:decimal];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDecimal:(NSDecimal)value {
    return [self initWithDecimal:value currency:[[CurrencySettings getInstance] getCurrency]];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDecimal:(NSDecimal)value currency:(NSString *)currencyCode {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _currencyCode = currencyCode;
        _value = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:value];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I have found a method which is called frequently in our internal JSON deserialisation implementation. It builds our data recursively using this `NSObject` method:

```c
[self setValue:value forKey:key]
```

## TL;DR;

We have an internal ObjC JSON deserialisation layer that through magic implements default methods for things implementing an interface. This calls on the following method frequently:

```c
[self setValue:value forKey:key]
```

## [NSObject setValue: forKey:]

[According to the docs it says the following](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue):

> If key identifies a to-one relationship, relate the object specified by value to the receiver, unrelating the previously related object if there was one. Given a collection object and a key that identifies a to-many relationship, relate the objects contained in the collection to the receiver, unrelating previously related objects if there were any.
>   The search pattern that setValue:forKey: uses is described in Accessor Search Patterns in Key-Value Coding Programming Guide.
>   **In a reference-counted environment, if the instance variable is accessed directly, value is retained.**

## Debugging and tracing

We have **Automatic Reference Counting** (ARC) enabled on the target and right now these are the only leaks we have currently in a pretty big project, and the usage of `Money.zero()` is used elsewhere very frequently as well, indicating it is not actually a problem with the `Money` class itself.

The memory graph for `Money` is not very informative and displays only this:

[image: Leaked Money]

The graph for `NSDecimalNumber` shows that `Money` is at fault, though:

[image: Leaked NSDecimalNumber]

Inspecting the graph for `Percent` will show the same sort of relationship.

**Making the properties lazy**

A workaround is to make the properties `lazy`. It does not give us any insights as to why it happened though, so this is why I am posting here.

```swift
@objcMembers
class Pricing: Mappable {
    lazy var price: Money = Money.zero()
    lazy var vat: Percent = Percent.zero()

    ...
}
```